# MV Refresh Group - Refresh Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

In our 12c database, I have created a materialized view refresh group for certain MVs that need to be refreshed on a weekly basis.

When trying to execute the materialized view refresh:

```
exec dbms_refresh.refresh('MY_MV_REFRESH_GROUP');
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I have found that this is due to the MVs needing to be recompiled.  Is there a way to add this logic to the refresh group itself or to the execute statement?  There are quite a few MVs there and the whole intent of creating the refresh group is so that I don't have to manually go through them.  Is there any way to have all MVs in the refresh group (or even all MVs in the specified schema) compiled and refreshed at once?  Any and all insight/tips would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:    I have taken a code recommended from Barbaros Özhan and now am executing the following:

```
declare
  v_compile  varchar2(250);
  v_refresh  varchar2(250);
begin
  for mv in
          (
          select *
            from all_mviews
           where owner = 'MY_SCHEMA' and mview_name like 'MV_PREFIX%'
          )
  loop
    v_compile := ('alter materialized view ' || mv.owner || '.' ||  mv.mview_name || ' compile');
    v_refresh := 'begin dbms_mview.refresh('''||mv.mview_name||''',''c''); end; ';
    dbms_output.put_line(v_compile);
    execute immediate v_compile;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_refresh);
    execute immediate v_refresh;
  end loop;          
end;
```

However, it still gets hung up on certain MVs.  Since it is using put-line I can tell which MV it gets hung up on and it gets hung up on compile.  If i remove the compile statement and just try to refresh(, 'C'), it still gets hung up.  The only way to ameliorate it that I have found is to find the MV in the schema browser and right-click and compile, then right-click and refresh.  I don't understand why the pl/sql wouldn't work but right-clicking would work.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using this loop through `user_objects` dictionary view :

```
declare
 v_command  varchar2(250);
begin
for c in
          (
          select *
            from user_objects o
           where regexp_like(o.object_type,'mater','i')
          )
loop
    v_command := 'begin dbms_mview.refresh('''||c.object_name||''',''c''); end; ';
    dbms_output.put_line(v_command);
  execute immediate v_command; 
end loop;          
end;
```

where **c** indicates complete refresh. <kbd>[Ref.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_mview.htm#i997279)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer and sorry for the delayed response.  I will try this now and let you know if this works.  Thank you!

Comment: Hello.  I was able to modify some of your code to get it to work for most of the MVs but it still gets hung up while compiling some.  I have to manually right click and compile, then right click and refresh in schema browser, which makes no sense to me.  Do you have any idea why that may be?  I have updated my post to show the code that I used from you and modified.

Comment: @nonoracle, in that case, it might be possible that your select cursor is restricting those MVs from selection

Comment: Hello.  Thank you for the response.  It is showing up in the selection and outputting to DBMS_OUTPUT but shows an error saying the object does not exist.  I then try to manually execute the statements and it does not work, then, when I go to that specific MV that it listed I can rightclick and compile and right-click and refresh with no errors.  It is very odd and I can't seem to make sense of it.